# ASP.NET Core MVC application with Identity Core and Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

How do I combine the identity framework version of ASP.NET Core with an Entity Framework 6 database?

Currently I have the following:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add<AutorizationActionFilter>();
    });
    services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>();
    var factory2 = new DatabaseContextFactory();
    //DatabaseContext inherits from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    services.AddScoped<DatabaseContext>(_ => factory2.Create());
}
```

I am getting the following error when starting the application:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Supernova.Crm.DataLayer.DomainModels.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Supernova.Crm.DataLayer.DomainModels.ApplicationUser]'.

How do I resolve this error? Is there a way to resolve the error without implementing `IUserStore` myself?

Maybe the package `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CoreCompat` is what I am looking for? I couldn't figure out yet how to use that package properly.

Comment: Do you have also app.UseIdentity() in you Configure method !?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am using app.UseAuthentication(); in the configure method. For app.UseIdentity I get a warning saying the method is deprecated.